# Render card details on another page when clicking specific card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-router-dom

Cards are coming from a JSON file. Code is from a file called paintings.js. Cards are all rendering properly and when clicked they bring me to blank paintingInfo.js page. My question is what should I include in this new paintingInfo.js page so that it renders the card I stored inn localstorage. Relatively new to React so any help would be much appreciated.Basically how do I access local storage in the paintingInfo.js page for it to render?

```
  state = {
    cardInfo: [...cardInfo]
  };

  goToPaintingInfo = (cardInfo) => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedPainting", cardInfo);
    this.props.history.push("/paintingInfo/:id");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar className="navCustom d-flex justify-space-between" bg="light" variant="light">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">SNR Arts</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="ml-auto navCust">
            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/paintings">Paintings</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            {/* print out cards here */}

            {this.state.cardInfo.map(card => {
              return (
                <div className="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 my-3" key={card.id}>
                  <img
                    src={card.image}
                    alt={card.name}
                    className="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded indvCard bg-dark"
                    onClick = {()=>this.goToPaintingInfo(card.id)}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of card, instead of `card.id` you need to send `card` only like,

```
onClick = {()=>this.goToPaintingInfo(card)}
```

```
goToPaintingInfo = (cardInfo) => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedPainting", JSON.stringify(cardInfo)); //store complete card
    this.props.history.push(`/paintingInfo/${cardInfo.id}`); //For this you must have Route to handle this request
}
```

Somewhere in Route, you must have

```
<Route path="/paintingInfo/:id" exact component={paintingInfo} /> //Write appropriate component name
```

`paintingInfo.js` file

```
state={
   card: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedPainting"))
}

render(){
   return(
     <div>
        <img src={this.state.card.image}
             alt={this.state.card.name}
             className="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded indvCard bg-dark"
        />
     </div>
   )
}
```

**Note:** Instead of `this.props.history.push`, you can make use of `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` package only.

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
```

```
goToPaintingInfo = (cardInfo) => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedPainting", cardInfo); //store complete card
    return <Redirect to={`/paintingInfo/${cardInfo.id}`} />; //For this you must have Route to handle this request
}
```

Comment: Try to print `card`  in `PaintingInfo.js` before return, and see if value stored in localstorage,

Comment: If your path is `"./images/{name of file}"` then you have to use `require` like ` src={require(this.state.card.image)}`. See the updated answer.

Comment: When you are doing this `localStorage.setItem("selectedPainting", cardInfo);` then do this `const item = localStorage.getItem("selectedPainting");` and check `if(item){this.props.history.push(`/paintingInfo/${cardInfo.id}`);}`

Comment: Or another hack is you can use some delay like,`setTimeout({this.props.history.push(`/paintingInfo/${cardInfo.id}`);},5000)`, will redirect after 5 sec.

Comment: Your image path is wrong, As your images are in public folder your image path should be `/images/filename`, remove `.` from image path.

Comment: Also remove `require` as I suggested previously.

Comment: What is path after inspecting?

Comment: do `console.log(this.state.card)`

Comment: check console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.card))

Comment: You need to stringify the object before saving and pase object before using it. check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much man!! Finally fixed the issue couldn't have done it without you I appreciate it so much :) !